# Запятая перед тире в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, авторская-пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в указанных местах?
Или тире заменяют эти запятые? (Тире поставлены в качестве интонационных авторских знаков, их нужно сохранить, вопрос только в запятых перед тире.)

> 1. Если вам кажется, что в жизни нужно что-то менять(,) — то вам не кажется.
> 2. Если вы чувствуете, что специалист вам не подходит(,) — задумайтесь, стоит ли продолжать с ним работу.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Если вам кажется, что в жизни нужно что-то менять, — то вам это не кажется.*
2. *Если вы чувствуете, что специалист вам не подходит, — стоит ли продолжать с ним работу?*

Попробуем обосновать постановку тире и запятой. Вряд ли стоит считать, что можно просто так добавить к запятой  **авторское** тире. (Обычно авторское интонационное тире ставится при отсутствии знаков или же оно заменяет запятую).

**Поэтому надо обратиться к правилу Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

В других случаях тире ставится после запятой, **закрывающей придаточную часть,** **при «переломе» конструкции, перед словом это и т. д.:**  *Однажды я спросил себя: а что, если он вернётся, неожиданно явится к тебе, — ты будешь рад?;  Что это был за случай, в котором было столько неясного, — **этого** он припомнить не мог;*

**Итак, по Розенталю, мы имеем право добавить тире, обосновав его каким-либо образом.** Слова ***это*** у нас нет, тогда надо увидеть в предложении "перелом конструкции" или еще что-нибудь увидеть.

В предложении (1)  тире обозначает неожиданное для читателя развитие темы.

В предложении (2) я бы такой перелом связала с тем, что одна часть интонационно плохо стыкуется с другой частью. Сравнить: *Если вы чувствуете, что специалист вам не подходит, **то** стоит ли продолжать с ним работу?*

Answer (score 1):

**1. Если вам кажется, что в жизни нужно что-то менять, — то вам это не кажется.**

Примечание. Предложение изменено, в первоначальном виде предложение "вам не кажется" как бы висело в пустоте, глагол *казаться* требует после себя дополнения.

**2. Если вы чувствуете, что специалист вам не подходит, — задумайтесь, стоит ли продолжать с ним работу.**

Запятая и тире стоят каждый по своей причиине и не отменяют друг друга.

В первом пункте запятая закрывает придаточное "что в жизни нужно что-то менять", а тире отделяет придаточное "то вам не кажется".

Во втором пункте запятая закрывает придаточное "что специалист вам не подходит", а тире в БСП отделяет блок "задумайтесь, стоит ли продолжать с ним работу".

Comment: Пожалуйста, Вы не могли бы объяснить мне смысл и структуру первого предложения, а то я никак не могу его понять. (Но, видимо, это неясно только мне).

Comment: @Sharon, Перечитал еще раз и понял, что не только Вам, но и мне. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @Sharon, Имеется в виду "Вам это не кажется — это есть на самом деле". А структуру сложного предложения я объяснил в ответе.

Comment: Да, спасибо, там очень не хватало слова "это". Хотя можно было бы еще так дополнить предложение: Если вам кажется, что в жизни нужно что-то менять, — то вам это не кажется, это действительно так

Answer (score 1):

*Что в жизни нужно что-то менять* и *что специалист вам не подходит* — это придаточные предложения, которые после себя **требуют постановки запятой**, а тире — это авторский (дополнительный, выделительный) знак.

Теоретически, конечно, интонационное тире ставится между любыми членами предложения.
Однако в представленных вами предложениях мне оно кажется не совсем оправданным.

Я бы оформила их так:
**Если вам кажется, что в жизни нужно что-то менять, — вам не кажется.

Если вы чувствуете, что специалист вам не подходит, — стоит ли продолжать с ним работу?**